# Morgan (node.js): Coloring status code (as in 'dev') while using custom format

Tags: node.js, logging

I am using morgan for logging in node.js.

I like the status code coloring provided in the predefined format mode 'dev', 
but I am using a custom format.

How can I get the same coloring as in 'dev' mode?

Per morgan documentation, dev format is the following :

```
 :method :url :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length]
```

When I use that it does not color :

```
// does not color
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length]'));
```

But when I use predefined 'dev' it does color!

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use chalkJS for coloring very easily.

```
import morgan from 'morgan';
import chalk from 'chalk'; // or you can use the require('chalk') syntax too

export const morganMiddleware = morgan(function (tokens, req, res) {
    return [
        '\n\n\n',
        chalk.hex('#ff4757').bold('  Morgan --> '),
        chalk.hex('#34ace0').bold(tokens.method(req, res)),
        chalk.hex('#ffb142').bold(tokens.status(req, res)),
        chalk.hex('#ff5252').bold(tokens.url(req, res)),
        chalk.hex('#2ed573').bold(tokens['response-time'](req, res) + ' ms'),
        chalk.hex('#f78fb3').bold('@ ' + tokens.date(req, res)),
        chalk.yellow(tokens['remote-addr'](req, res)),
        chalk.hex('#fffa65').bold('from ' + tokens.referrer(req, res)),
        chalk.hex('#1e90ff')(tokens['user-agent'](req, res)),
        '\n\n\n',
    ].join(' ');
});

app.use(morganMiddleware);
```

Answer (score 8):

@Adam Reis pointed in the really nice direction. I came up with this solution:

```js
morgan.token('splitter', (req) => {
    return "\x1b[36m--------------------------------------------\x1b[0m\n";
});
morgan.token('statusColor', (req, res, args) => {
    // get the status code if response written
    var status = (typeof res.headersSent !== 'boolean' ? Boolean(res.header) : res.headersSent)
        ? res.statusCode
        : undefined

    // get status color
    var color = status >= 500 ? 31 // red
        : status >= 400 ? 33 // yellow
            : status >= 300 ? 36 // cyan
                : status >= 200 ? 32 // green
                    : 0; // no color

    return '\x1b[' + color + 'm' + status + '\x1b[0m';
});
server.use(morgan(`:splitter\x1b[33m:method\x1b[0m \x1b[36m:url\x1b[0m :statusColor :response-time ms - length|:res[content-length]`));
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I use this chalk morgan configuration for all my work , and include it as a middleware in the express app.

```
const morgan = require ('morgan');
const chalk = require ('chalk');

const  morganChalk = morgan(function (tokens, req, res) {
    return [
        chalk.green.bold(tokens.method(req, res)),
        chalk.red.bold(tokens.status(req, res)),
        chalk.white(tokens.url(req, res)),
        chalk.yellow(tokens['response-time'](req, res) + ' ms'),
    ].join(' ');
});

module.exports = {
    morganChalk
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it cannot colourise your output to console by default.

You can either refer to this article which takes help of the 'chalk' module in order to colourise the output to console.

Or else what I did was I used the default 'dev' configuration and I added an extra config for my custom tokens which left the default dev output as it is.
Something like this:

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(morgan('auth_id - :userid user_email - :email'));
```

This will do what you are trying to do but, the second output of morgan will be in a newline.

Comment: relevant discussion on morgan github : https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/53 (with examples on how to use chalk)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the same formatting function as defined in morgan's source code for the `dev` format: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js#L183-L206

Answer (score 1):

Also now chalk supports template string function, so you can create colored *dev* morgan string like this:

```
app.use(morgan(chalk`:method :url {green :status} :response-time ms - :res[content-length]`));
```

Answer (score 1):

simply put "dev" into it:

```
morgan("dev")
```

or before your configuration, like this:

```
app.use(
  morgan(
    "dev",
    ":method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms - [:date[clf]]"
  )
);
```