# Express morgan logger - "de-escape" query strings

Tags: node.js, express, morgan

I am using morgan like this on an Express server:

```
const morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

In my logs I usually see something like this:

```
GET /?prompt_ids={%22foo%22:%22bar%22} 200 122.495 ms - -
```

my question is - is there a way to log the query string using morgan, where the characters are not escaped?

that would look something like this:

```
GET /?prompt_ids={"foo":"bar"} 200 122.495 ms - -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to apply the JavaScript function `decodeURI()` to the url logged by morgan.

You can define a custom logging layout like the 'dev' one with this small change.

To make things easy in your case, we can take the details of the 'dev' layout 
 directly [from the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan).

So, instead of `app.use(morgan('dev'))`, just use :

```
morgan(function (tokens, req, res) {
  return [
    tokens.method(req, res),
    decodeURI(tokens.url(req, res)), // I changed this from the doc example, which is the 'dev' config.
    tokens.status(req, res),
    tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'), '-',
    tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms'
  ].join(' ')
})
```

EDIT : if this doesn't work well, you can use `decodeURIComponent()` instead of `decodeURI()`, as per this question : [NodeJS Express encodes the URL - how to decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576659/nodejs-express-encodes-the-url-how-to-decode)

Comment: thanks, this works great, one gripe - do you know how to get the "right" color on the status code? is there some pre-built logic for that

Comment: @AlexanderMills this is a different question :), and unfortunately I don't know. By the way, there is already an opened question on the subject in SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284015/morgan-node-js-coloring-status-code-as-in-dev-while-using-custom-format

Comment: that's ok, I filed an issue with them, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Thank you. By the way, I found this discussion too : https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/53 . There is an example on how to use chalk module to colorize.